# SQL modeling and design tools?

Tags: software-recommendation, database, diagram, sql

I would like to know which tool do you use for modeling tables, relationships, etc, generic database modeling, in Ubuntu.

It would be good if that tool generate SQL scripts, and a plus with those scripts are SQLite compatible, but thats not necessary.

Currently, I am using Enterprise Architect for that under a virtual machine, which kind of sucks. I was able to run it under Wine, but not as good as I want to. It is a complete tool for modeling anything in this world, and right now I do not need so much.

Comment: u need UML Modelling tools..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try [DIA](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/). You can use UML to create/model Databases and use one of the officially [supported Scripts](http://live.gnome.org/Dia/Links#line-34) to convert it to SQL.

For instance you can find a basic How-To using DIA and TeDia2SQL at http://left.subtree.org/2007/12/05/database-design-with-dia/

Answer (score 11):

Another good option is [mysql-workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). It can easily be installed using `apt-get` (the third command will do, yet I prefer to update and search first):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-cache search mysql-workbench
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

Then you can just type `mysql` in the HUB and voila.

[image]

It works like a charm. There is also a download from their website, yet that gave me in 12.10 a dependency error (the download is for 12.04 so that might explain it).

Others have also referred to: [druid](http://druid.sourceforge.net/index.html) and [DBDesigner](http://fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/screenshots.php). There is also another post on DB design [on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/112565/what-floss-db-design-tool-for-linux-would-you-recommend).

Comment: +1 for mysql workbench. You can also synch changes to a mysql database.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [ArguoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/) with its [SQL plugin](http://argouml-sql.tigris.org/).

Comment: this answer is showing up in the low quality review queue???  So here goes the newbie blather:  Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Answer (score 0):

I use [ERBuilder data modeler](https://soft-builder.com/en/) under wine for modeling my PostgreSQL database and generating SQL script or directly the database. It works fine with wine and I think its support also SQLite.