# Is there an Postgres ERD tool (or pgAdmin III plugin)?

Tags: software-recommendation, database, postgresql, diagram

Don't hold it against me, but I have a fond memory of MS SQL Server Management Studio. I could very easily generate an ERD diagram from an existing database. Tables, relationships, the works. You could even use the diagram to edit the database structure.

I can't find such a tool in pgAdmin III. <del>Am I missing something?</del> [It seems there isn't one built-in.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_database_tools#Features_-_visual_design_and_reverse_engineering) Is there a plugin? Or a separate tool?

(I have found [references to using Dia and other tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89455/sql-modeling-and-design-tools) to model first and then generate the SQL to create the database. This is nice, but secondary to my primary goal which is to generate a diagram from an existing PostgreSQL database. And to truly replicate Management Studio functionality, the application would have to work in both directions.)

Answer (score 1):

### EMS SQL Manager for PostgreSQL

http://www.sqlmanager.net/products/postgresql/manager

Powerful visual database designer

```
Two diagram notations (IDEF1x and IE)
Useful diagram navigation tool
Reverse engineering
Several pages in one diagram to divide diagram into different subject areas
Ability to create, edit and drop tables and table fields, set links between tables visually
Ability to add comments to diagram
Saving as image or printing database diagram
A lot of visual customization options
```

It is a windows program but works preety fine under wine

Comment: I was hoping for something FLOSS and native, but thanks for taking the time to test it under Wine!

Answer (score 1):

### SchemaSpy

http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net

Lightweight, easy install, straight to the point and comprehensive.

Licensing: LGPL 2.1 (linked from main page)

Comment: interesting, that also led me to schemacrawler.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 1):

### Schema Crawler

http://www.schemacrawler.com

"SchemaCrawler is a free database schema discovery and comprehension tool... output the schema and data in a readable text format. The output serves for database documentation, and is designed to be diff-ed against other database schemas. SchemaCrawler also generates schema diagrams."

deb installer: https://github.com/adriens/schemacrawler-deb 
Licensing: https://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/license.html (GPLv3)